# Reseting label back to design-time .Text value

Tags: c#, winforms, label, default-value

I have a bunch of labels that I set their value in the designer and later during `runtime` update them, but after using them, I want to set them back to their default value. My intent with this is to reduce the amount of large code to help make it easier to read.

random example like, setting in the designer of `lbl_fruit` `Text = no fruits available currently` then

```
*code*
lbl_fruits.Text = "banana";
*code*
lbl_fruits.ResetText(); // I want something like this
lbl_fruits.Text = "no fruits available currently"; // Instead of this
```

The `.ResetText();` doesn't work for this as the label text gets cleaned instead of returning to "no fruits available currently"

My current solution is making a custom label control.

```
public class ExLabel : Label
    {
        private string defaultValue = "";
        public string DefaultValue
        {
            get { return defaultValue; }
            set { defaultValue = value; this.Invalidate(); }
        }
        protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            defaultValue = this.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("This code is being run");
            base.OnControlAdded(e);
        }

        public void ResetValue()
        {
            this.Text = defaultValue;
        }
    }
```

This code currently solves my problem if I use the custom propriety I made, but for me the ideal solution would be to have the `design-time text` value as the default value and not an extra propriety I made. `OnControlAdded()` does not get executed, `OnPaint()` runs again when `lbl_fruits.Text = "banana";` happens.

So the question is: Which event I can override so the code gets executed as soon as the label is loaded but doesn't run twice. And also, is there a simpler way of approaching this?

Comment: What you call *design-time* value will be saved in resource and loaded during `InitializeComponents()` call. You can do the same. Keeping the current design you have to set `DefaultValue` in form designer and simply set `Text` value from the setter.

Comment: *"No fruits available currently"* imply you are doing some sort of *validation* or displaying the status. Not sure if default values are really that much useful, since you may want multiple errors: not available, negative number entered, date is from past, etc. Maybe you just want multiple labels and control their visibility depending on error? Or make a dedicated error class holding all the errors and corresponding text?

Comment: I believe you need to change the values back to defaults after executing some logic. Ideal way would be to write a helper method to make sure all the controls are being reset on given action. 
Or you can have a Dictionary<Object,String> mapping which can be called to clear and reset.

Comment: The value of those is going to be for client data being displayed, and some of the fields can be null, so it can either be data brought by the database or no data, they are going to display "no data in x field", then once it gets loaded its going to become the value needed to be displayed, and when the user loads data from the next client, everything gonna be reset and only the fields which have data are going to be loaded. Also when the user leaves the page every single page is going to be reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the solution I used was this:

```
public class ExLabel : Label
{
    private string defaultValue = "";
    public string DefaultValue
    {
        get { return defaultValue; }
        set { defaultValue = value; this.Invalidate(); }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(defaultValue == "" && !this.Text.Contains("exLabel"))
        {
            defaultValue = this.Text;
        }
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    public void ResetValue()
    {
        this.Text = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ExLabel : Label
{
    private string defaultValue = "";
    public string DefaultValue
    {
        get { return defaultValue; }
        set { defaultValue = value; this.Invalidate(); }
    }
    protected override void OnControlAdded(ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        defaultValue = this.Text;
        MessageBox.Show("This code is being run");
        base.OnControlAdded(e);
    }

    public void ResetValue()
    {
        this.Text = defaultValue;
    }
}
```